# react-native-gifted-chat How to send on pressing return

Tags: react-native, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

How do I make the return button on the mobile keyboard send the message instead of creating a new line? I tried using `onSubmitEditing` in the `textInputProps` but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own `ChatComposer` and pass the `onSubmitEditing` prop in the `textInputProps` in there. In order to prevent keyboard dismiss you also need to set `blurOnSubmit` to false.

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])


const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
}, [])

const ChatComposer = (
    props: ComposerProps & {
      onSend: SendProps<IMessage>["onSend"]
      text: SendProps<IMessage>["text"]
    }
) => {
    return (
      <Composer
        {...props}
        textInputProps={{
          ...props.textInputProps,
          blurOnSubmit: false,
          multiline: false,
          onSubmitEditing: () => {
            if (props.text && props.onSend) {
              props.onSend({ text: props.text.trim() }, true)
            }
          },
        }}
      />
    )
 }

return (
    <GiftedChat messages={messages} onSend={onSend} renderComposer={ChatComposer} />
  )
```

If you want to remove the default `send` button from the text input field on the right, you need to pass a custom `renderSend` button, which could be empty, e.g.

```js
renderSend={() => {}}
```

Notice, that I have tested all of the above on iOS only. Android might behave differently.